# ajax listener was not updated the panels for selected item in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Iam trying to update a panel based selected data using primefaces selectonemenu and ajax listener was taken care by updating the panels.But my panel was not updated and selected item was shown at console window.That means ,The ajax call was got into managed bean.but its not updated at faces pages and mentioned my code

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1"  style="align:center;width:80%" styleClass="companyHeaderGrid">
        <p:row>
            <p:column><h:outputLabel for="runobject" value="Run Object: " /></p:column>
            <p:column>  
             <p:selectOneMenu id="selectedState" value="#{TAScheduleBean.selectedRunObjectItem}"   >
             <p:ajax listener="#{TAScheduleBean.changePanelState}"  render="@this"  update=":form:displayDailyPanel"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="Select One" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{TAScheduleBean.runObjectsValue}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            </p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row id="displayDailyPanel"   rendered="#{TAScheduleBean.appSelectedRunObject eq 'Daily'}">
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value=" N days" />
                        <p:outputLabel  value="Days=" /><p:inputText id="s"/>
            </p:column>
    </p:panelGrid>
```

***I read relevant issues in the same forums and other forums also***. but the issue is not resolved.How can i resolve this.Please help me

Update :-

ManagedBean

```
public class TAScheduleBean extends TASBean  {
        private String selectedRunObjectItem="";
        private  String appSelectedRunObject="";
        TAScheduleBean(){

        }
        public void changePanelState(){
        String methodName="changePanelState";

        setPanelIsVisible(true);
        TALogger.log(Logger.INFO, className,
                methodName, "---------"+getSelectedRunObjectItem());
        setAppSelectedRunObject(getSelectedRunObjectItem().trim());

        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all please post your Managed bean code.

Comment: check the managed bean code

Comment: I can't see the method runObjectsValue. Please always post full code.

Comment: Try to use panelGrid id inplace of :form:displayDailyPanel in update

Comment: I got getSelectedRunObjectItem() value in manegedbean when selected item.But its not updated into row at xhtml page.If refresh the page then shown that rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.I resolved the issue.when we are selected item up to that time the row was not created because we called 'rendered' attribute.So i created panel and mentioned below code

```
<p:panel id="toppanel">  <------- added panel

<p:panelGrid columns="1"  style="align:center;width:80%" styleClass="companyHeaderGrid">
        <p:row>
            <p:column><h:outputLabel for="runobject" value="Run Object: " /></p:column>
            <p:column>  
             <p:selectOneMenu id="selectedState" value="#{TAScheduleBean.selectedRunObjectItem}"   >
             <p:ajax listener="#{TAScheduleBean.changePanelState}"  render="@this"  update="toppanel"/>  <------changed
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="Select One" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{TAScheduleBean.runObjectsValue}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            </p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row id="displayDailyPanel"   rendered="#{TAScheduleBean.appSelectedRunObject eq 'Daily'}">
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value=" N days" />
                        <p:outputLabel  value="Days=" /><p:inputText id="s"/>
            </p:column>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

then its working fine.